# Parallel stream java avoid overhead

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing

Suppose I have a list I want to iterate parallel over only when the list is bigger than N. This because it will probably give more overhead to do things parallel so I want to limit it to a certain number. Is there a java parallel stream configuration which enables me to do so?

Of course I can do an if statement checking the size. But it would be cooler if I can configure it somewhere.

Comment: You can create a custom Spliterator that only splits when `estimateSize() > N`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating different streams based on size doesn't sound all that bad. Create a helper function and it becomes almost transparent:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> selectStream(final Collection<T> coll) {
  return coll.size() > 10000
      ? coll.parallelStream()
      : coll.stream();
}

selectStream(yourCollection).map(x -> x).collect(toList());
```